# pip install on AWS? Can found geos_c

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, shapely, geos

I got a DLL error when I import shapely.

I have run my code on a local server, it works. ( I got same error when I pip install shapely, but it works after I installed shapely.whl )

I run this code on AWS, it shows out again. When I pip install "c/...path.../shapely.whl", noticed can not found this document.

local machine: windows 10 with 64 bits
python 3.5
shapely version 1.57, both of pip install file or .whl file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH46v.jpg)

Comment: did you find the solution?